# How to sniff email with https on Windows?

Tags: tls, email, sniffer, wireshark, email-spoofing

I am working now on Windows 7 and I want to see if I can sniff an email content on it with Wireshark.  So all right with http but with https I can't at this moment and I don't understand how.  You think I need Kali Linux? Or I need something to do to realize it on Windows

Comment: So I done with Fiddle on my own machine and I saw what I send to a person on gmail.
Sounds good.
Now what I want to doing it`s to see an email on a network where I`m connected.
So two men(me and x) are on the network like wifi.I want to see what x send in a email on this network.Sorry if I meant well but I`m beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fiddler if you want to sniff traffic on your own machine. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

If you, however, want to sniff SSL traffic on your network without access to the machines communicating, it will not be possible to make any sense of the traffic, since it is encrypted (https is HTTP over SSL).

Comment: Not true. It is possible to do, it's just not as straightforwards as intercepting cleartext information.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTPS traffic is encrypted, you can trick a computer into not using HTTPS but for this you'll need to setup a man in the middle attack. Then use something like `sslstrip` to trick the client into not using HTTPS. Kali linux has all these tools build in, so that would be a good OS to start with.

Comment: Correct, you would need a MITM attack for this to succeed. Also, did you mean `sslstrip`?

Comment: So I done with Fiddle on my own machine and I saw what I send to a person on gmail.
Sounds good.
Now what I want to doing it`s to see an email on a network where I`m connected.
So two men(me and x) are on the network like wifi.I want to see what x send in a email on this network.Sorry if I meant well but I`m beginner

Comment: You cannot sniff it without MITM attack. That means either access to the computer itself or the router. Do you have it?

Comment: You need to be connected to the same network, setup a MiTM with arp-spoof or cain and able. This will allow you to reroute all the traffic through your computer. The messages will still be encrypted tho, so now you need to trick the victim into not using https by seting up sslstrip. But if you are a beginner, i'd recommend starting by setting up a MiTM, see how that works. From there you can start to play with sslstrip. One step at a time :)

Comment: edvinas.me <--Yes,I have access on the router with him.BadSkillz<--I used Cain and Abel with ARP POISINING,and I saw there what he saw at HTTP,and I want now,I think to see what sslstrip it is,and play with it ? I read that it is transform HTTPS -> HTTP